# Django problem with movie types not displaying

Tags: python, django, types

[image]Hi Stackoverflow people,
you will help in the following matters.

My models:

```
class Movie(models.Model):

    HORROR = 1
    COMEDY = 2
    SCI_FI = 3
    DRAMA = 4
    ANIMATION = 5
    EDUCATION = 6
    THRILLER = 7
    MUSICAL = 8
    WAR = 9
    HISTORICAL = 10
    ROMANCE = 11
    SPORTS = 12
    WESTERN = 13
    DOCUMENTARY = 14
    NONE = 0

 types = (
    (HORROR, 'Horror'),
    (COMEDY, 'Comedy'),
    (SCI_FI, 'Sci-Fi'),
    (DRAMA, 'Drama'),
    (ANIMATION, 'Animation'),
    (EDUCATION, 'Education'),
    (THRILLER, 'Thriller'),
    (MUSICAL, 'Musical'),
    (WAR, 'War'),
    (HISTORICAL, 'Historical'),
    (ROMANCE, 'Romance'),
    (SPORTS, 'Sports'),
    (WESTERN, 'Western'),
    (DOCUMENTARY, 'Documentary'),
    (None, 'No information'),

     )
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
 type = models.IntegerField(choices=types, default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

My urls:

```
path('more/<int:id>', views.MovieDetail, name='MovieDetail'),
path('Types/movie/<int:type_id>/', views.TypeMovies, name='TypeMovies'),
```

My views:

```
@login_required
def TypeMovies(request, type_id):
    movie = Movie.objects.filter(type=type_id)
    return render(request, 'MyPage/MovieDetail.html', {'movie': movie})


@login_required
def AllMovies(request):                            
    movie = Movie.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'MyPage/AllMovies.html', { 'movie': movie, 'type': Movie.types }),
```

My templates:

```
<ul class="movieCategories">
            {% for type in type %}

                <li><a href="{% url 'MyPage:MovieDetail' type.0 %}"><h4>{{ type.1 }}</h4></a></li>
            {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

in templates I also tried {% url 'MyPage: MovieDetail' movie.id%} and movie.type.id
And I am only afraid that it was not found

The problem is that I have a list of film genres and when I want to click one of them, it redirects me to a given film from this genre.

Comment: You don't appear to have a URL for `MovieDetail`? Also it's unusual not to have completely lower case paths for your URLs, you should probably consider that.

Comment: I corrected may path

Comment: Do you have any error? Can you show where `MyPage` namespace is defined?

Comment: @kubaWróbel ` it redirects me to a given film from this genre` and instead it should...?

Comment: this will not work. "'type': Movie.types",, also "{% for type in type %}" this is not correct

Comment: And have you correctly setup namespacing etc for `MyPage`? I can't see it outside of the template path and your call to `url`. Also what actually renders to the page?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want. Do you want list of all movies and clicking on movie name you want to redirect to page to show details of movie?

Comment: No,
I want my list of movie genres to have a hyperlink that will redirect me to my "MovieDetail.html" template

Comment: app_name = "MyPage"